# How to generate new rows depending on sting value from one column in sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need to generate new rows depending on value from "Number" column. I've tried CHARINDEX and STUFF function without any success.

Exampledata (where ".." means in between, "| means and):

```
CREATE TABLE mytable(
   Row         VARCHAR(3) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
  ,Description VARCHAR(11)
  ,Number      VARCHAR(26)
);
INSERT INTO mytable(Row,Description,Number) VALUES ('100','Testing','1105..1110|2805|2820..2830');
INSERT INTO mytable(Row,Description,Number) VALUES (NULL,NULL,NULL);
INSERT INTO mytable(Row,Description,Number) VALUES (NULL,NULL,NULL);
```

Expected output:

```
+-----+-------------+--------+
| Row | Description | Number |
+-----+-------------+--------+
| 100 | Testing     |   1105 |
| 100 | Testing     |   1106 |
| 100 | Testing     |   1107 |
| 100 | Testing     |   1108 |
| 100 | Testing     |   1109 |
| 100 | Testing     |   1110 |
| 100 | Testing     |   2805 |
| 100 | Testing     |   2820 |
| 100 | Testing     |   2821 |
| 100 | Testing     |   2822 |
| 100 | Testing     |   2823 |
| 100 | Testing     |   2824 |
| 100 | Testing     |   2825 |
| 100 | Testing     |   2826 |
| 100 | Testing     |   2827 |
| 100 | Testing     |   2828 |
| 100 | Testing     |   2829 |
| 100 | Testing     |   2830 |
+-----+-------------+--------+
```

Comment: _"I've tried CHARINDEX and STUFF function without any success."_ What did you try, specifically?

Comment: To get where ".." and "|" are in the string i used Charindex as below:
CHARINDEX('..', [Number], 2) AS MatchPosition,
CHARINDEX('|', [Number], 1) AS MatchPosition

And then i used STUFF to replace, but I cant manage to replace into new rows to get correct values.

Comment: Probably unrelated, but: the second and third INSERT statement of your sample data will not work as you can't store `NULL` in the primary key column.

Comment: The data does not contain Null, the empty rows was generated by Excel, sorry for the inconvenience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@vasdan, could you please check following SQL script
Please note that I used to user-defined function which you can find similar ones on the web
First one is [SQL split function](http://www.kodyaz.com/articles/t-sql-convert-split-delimeted-string-as-rows-using-xml.aspx)
The second is [SQL numbers function](http://www.kodyaz.com/articles/sql-server-tsql-cte-numbers-table.aspx)

```
;with cte as (
    select 
        t.row,
        t.description,
        t.number,
        s.id grpno,
        replace(s.val,'..','|') as val
    from mytable as t
    cross apply dbo.split(t.Number,'|') s
), cte2 as (
select distinct
    row,
    description,
    grpno,
    case when ( count(*) over (partition by row, grpno) ) = 1 then null else 'X' end as range,
    min(s.val) over (partition by row, grpno) minval,
    max(s.val) over (partition by row, grpno) maxval
from cte
cross apply dbo.split(cte.val,'|') s
)
select
row,description,i
from cte2
cross apply dbo.NumbersTable(minval,maxval,1) n
```

Here is the output

[image]

If you need help, I'ld like to help you further on this example

Comment: Thank you @Eralper, this post helped me to solve the challenge.

Answer (score 1):

Use a recursive CTE to bulk create the numbers, use a parameter for the big string, insert only those that appear in the string

```
with CTE as
(
select 1105 as NN
union all
select NN + 1
from CTE
where NN < 2830
)
insert into MyTable
select 100, 'Testing', NN
from CTE
where @MyString like '%'+NN+'%'
```

Answer (score -1):

The easiest way is to create a Numbers table for yourself.  Having a numbers table is useful in numerous situations just like this one.  It allows you to do very easy SQL queries on ranges of numbers.

Check out this MSDN article: [The SQL Server Numbers Table, Explained](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4176/the-sql-server-numbers-table-explained--part-1/)

Once you have a numbers table, you can easily populate your target table with values "WHERE numbers.number between 1105 and 1110"

SQL 2005 introduced the Common Table Expression (CTE) and the ROW_NUMBER() window function enabling in-line creation of numbers tables.
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766(v=sql.105).aspx

Table Value Constructor's (TVC) were introduced in SQL 2008 which offers a very compact way to create a numbers table tailored specifically to the precise number of rows you need. 
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd776382(v=sql.110).aspx

-- Further reading: http://dataeducation.com/you-require-a-numbers-table/

Comment: not the one that downvoted, but a suggestion if anyone's going to go this route, it's probably best to stay away from the `between` operator, as it's not consistent with different database implementations.  A better way is to use `>=` and `<=` respectively.  This makes it a little more clear what your intent is too, as some db's use the `between` operator as inclusive, and some don't.

Comment: The between operator **is** consistent across all DBMS implementations (that I know of). Which database does not implement that correctly?